# GUI screen not opening

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I have an issue with my code where the function destroyu2r, its to be renamed, won't close and open back up to the function user2roll. The issue is with the button itself I suppose. I click it to no avail. I'm stumped on what to do. Any suggestions?

```
def destroyu2r():
    user2roll.destroy()
    global destroyu2r
    global score1
    r1=random.choice(d6)
    r2=random.choice(d6)
    r3=random.choice(d6)
    destroyu2r=tk.Tk()
    destroyu2r.geometry("640x480")
    destroyu2r.title(user1)
    tk.Label(destroyu2r,text=("Your first roll... A",r1,"!")).pack()
    tk.Label(destroyu2r,text="").pack()
    tk.Label(destroyu2r,text=("And your second roll is... A",r2,"1")).pack
    tk.Label(destroyu2r,text="").pack
    if r1 == r2:
        score1=score1+r1+r2+r3+10
        tk.Label(destroyu2r,text=("As your first two rolls were the same, you get an extra 10 points added to your score and your third roll is..",r3,"!")).pack()
        tk.Label(destroyu2r,text=("Your total score is now... ",score1,"!")).pack()
        tk.Label(destroyu2r,text="").pack()
        tk.Button(destroyu2r,text=(user2,"'s turn."),height="2",width=480,command=user2roll).pack()
    else:
        roll=r1+r2
        if roll in odd:
            score1=score1+r1+r2-5
            tk.Label(destroyu2r,text=("You rolled  ",r1," and ", r2,". Together they add up to ",roll,". As ",roll," is an odd number, ",r1," and ",r2," will be added to your score, then 5 points will be deducted.")).pack()
            tk.Label(destroyu2r,text=("You total score is now... ",score1,"!")).pack()
            tk.Label(destroyu2r,text="").pack()
            tk.Button(destroyu2r,text=(user2,"'s turn."),height="2",width=480,command=user2roll).pack()
            if score1 <= 0:
                destroyfu1r()
                gameendscreen()
        else:
            score1=score1+r1+r2+10
            tk.Label(destroyu2r,text=("You rolled  ",r1," and ", r2,". Together they add up to ",roll,". As ",roll," is an even number, ",r1," and ",r2," will be added to your score, then 10 points will be added.")).pack()
            tk.Label(destroyu2r,text=("Your total score is now... ",score1,"!")).pack()
            tk.Label(destroyu2r,text="").pack()
            tk.Button(destroyu2r,text=(user2,"'s turn."),height="2",width=480,command=user2roll).pack()
```

creates this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR9No.png).

Full code of the section is below.

```
import random
import time
import tkinter as tk
import os
from turtle import goto

score1=0
score2=0
d6=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
even=[2,4,6,8,10,12]
odd=[1,3,5,7,9,11]

def destroyu2r():
    user2roll.destroy()
    global destroyu2r
    global score1
    r1=random.choice(d6)
    r2=random.choice(d6)
    r3=random.choice(d6)
    destroyu2r=tk.Tk()
    destroyu2r.geometry("640x480")
    destroyu2r.title(user1)
    tk.Label(destroyu2r,text=("Your first roll... A",r1,"!")).pack()
    tk.Label(destroyu2r,text="").pack()
    tk.Label(destroyu2r,text=("And your second roll is... A",r2,"1")).pack
    tk.Label(destroyu2r,text="").pack
    if r1 == r2:
        score1=score1+r1+r2+r3+10
        tk.Label(destroyu2r,text=("As your first two rolls were the same, you get an extra 10 points added to your score and your third roll is..",r3,"!")).pack()
        tk.Label(destroyu2r,text=("Your total score is now... ",score1,"!")).pack()
        tk.Label(destroyu2r,text="").pack()
        tk.Button(destroyu2r,text=(user2,"'s turn."),height="2",width=480,command=user2roll).pack()
    else:
        roll=r1+r2
        if roll in odd:
            score1=score1+r1+r2-5
            tk.Label(destroyu2r,text=("You rolled  ",r1," and ", r2,". Together they add up to ",roll,". As ",roll," is an odd number, ",r1," and ",r2," will be added to your score, then 5 points will be deducted.")).pack()
            tk.Label(destroyu2r,text=("You total score is now... ",score1,"!")).pack()
            tk.Label(destroyu2r,text="").pack()
            tk.Button(destroyu2r,text=(user2,"'s turn."),height="2",width=480,command=user2roll).pack()
            if score1 <= 0:
                destroyfu1r()
                gameendscreen()
        else:
            score1=score1+r1+r2+10
            tk.Label(destroyu2r,text=("You rolled  ",r1," and ", r2,". Together they add up to ",roll,". As ",roll," is an even number, ",r1," and ",r2," will be added to your score, then 10 points will be added.")).pack()
            tk.Label(destroyu2r,text=("Your total score is now... ",score1,"!")).pack()
            tk.Label(destroyu2r,text="").pack()
            tk.Button(destroyu2r,text=(user2,"'s turn."),height="2",width=480,command=user2roll).pack()

def user1roll():
    global user1roll
    global score1
    r1=random.choice(d6)
    r2=random.choice(d6)
    r3=random.choice(d6)
    user1roll=tk.Tk()
    user1roll.geometry("640x480")
    user1roll.title(user1)
    tk.Label(user1roll,text=("Your first roll... A",r1,"!")).pack()
    tk.Label(user1roll,text="").pack()
    tk.Label(user1roll,text=("And your second roll is... A",r2,"1")).pack
    tk.Label(user1roll,text="").pack
    if r1 == r2:
        score1=score1+r1+r2+r3+10
        tk.Label(user1roll,text=("As your first two rolls were the same, you get an extra 10 points added to your score and your third roll is..",r3,"!")).pack()
        tk.Label(user1roll,text=("Your total score is now... ",score1,"!")).pack()
        tk.Label(user1roll,text="").pack()
        tk.Button(user1roll,text=(user2,"'s turn."),height="2",width=480,command=user2roll).pack()
    else:
        roll=r1+r2
        if roll in odd:
            score1=score1+r1+r2-5
            tk.Label(user1roll,text=("You rolled  ",r1," and ", r2,". Together they add up to ",roll,". As ",roll," is an odd number, ",r1," and ",r2," will be added to your score, then 5 points will be deducted.")).pack()
            tk.Label(user1roll,text=("You total score is now... ",score1,"!")).pack()
            tk.Label(user1roll,text="").pack()
            tk.Button(user1roll,text=(user2,"'s turn."),height="2",width=480,command=user2roll).pack()
            if score1 <= 0:
                destroyu1r()
                gameendscreen()
        else:
            score1=score1+r1+r2+10
            tk.Label(user1roll,text=("You rolled  ",r1," and ", r2,". Together they add up to ",roll,". As ",roll," is an even number, ",r1," and ",r2," will be added to your score, then 10 points will be added.")).pack()
            tk.Label(user1roll,text=("Your total score is now... ",score1,"!")).pack()
            tk.Label(user1roll,text="").pack()
            tk.Button(user1roll,text=(user2,"'s turn."),height="2",width=480,command=user2roll).pack()

def destroyu1r():
    user1roll.destroy()

def destroyfu1r():
    destroyu2r.destroy()

def gameendscreen():
    print("HI")
    
def destroyfu2r():
    user2roll.destroy()

def user2roll():
    destroyu1r()
    global user2roll
    global score2
    r4=random.choice(d6)
    r5=random.choice(d6)
    r6=random.choice(d6)
    user2roll=tk.Tk()
    user2roll.geometry("640x480")
    user2roll.title(user2)
    tk.Label(user2roll,text=("Your first roll... A",r4,"!")).pack()
    tk.Label(user2roll,text="").pack()
    tk.Label(user2roll,text=("And your second roll is... A",r5,"1")).pack()
    tk.Label(user2roll,text="").pack()
    if r4 == r5:
        score2=score2+r4+r5+r6+10
        tk.Label(user2roll,text=("As your first two rolls were the same, you your rolls, ",r4," and ",r5,", and you get an extra 10 points added to your score and your third roll is... ",r6,"!")).pack()
        tk.Label(user2roll,text=("Your total score is now... ",score2,"!")).pack()
        tk.Label(user2roll,text="").pack()
        tk.Button(user2roll,text=(user1,"'s turn."),height="2",width=480,command=destroyu2r).pack()
    else:
        roll=r4+r5
        if roll in odd:
            score2=score2+r4+r5-5
            tk.Label(user2roll,text=("You rolled  ",r4," and ", r5,". Together they add up to ",roll,". As ",roll," is an odd number, ",r4," and ",r5," will be added to your score, then 5 points will be deducted.")).pack()
            tk.Label(user2roll,text=("You total score is now... ",score2,"!")).pack()
            tk.Label(user2roll,text="").pack()
            tk.Button(user2roll,text=(user1,"'s turn."),height="2",width=480,command=destroyu2r).pack()
            if score2 <= 0:
                destroyfu2r()
                gameendscreen()
        else:
            score2=score2+r4+r5+10
            tk.Label(user2roll,text=("You rolled  ",r4," and ", r5,". Together they add up to ",roll,". As ",roll," is an even number, ",r4," and ",r5," will be added to your score, then 10 points will be added.")).pack()
            tk.Label(user2roll,text=("Your total score is now... ",score2,"!")).pack()
            tk.Label(user2roll,text="").pack()
            tk.Button(user2roll,text=(user1,"'s turn."),height="2",width=480,command=destroyu2r).pack()
user1roll()
```

Comment: Don't name functions and variables the same thing, especially when you declare the variables to be global (which is generally a bad idea anyway, but a different topic). You call both your function and a variable within it `destroyu2r`. Refactor one of them.

Comment: run code in console/terminal `python script.py` to see all error messages.